# Deleting duplicate XML attributes - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have a situation where i have duplicate XML attributes in an SQL Server column.

DB fiddle for sql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bfd7d8

Table:

```
create table test12
(
  id int,
  data xml
  );

  insert into test12 (id,data)
  values (1,
    '<test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
    <Value>Long</Value>
</test1>

    <test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
<Value>Long</Value>
    </test1>'

  )
```

The XML in question is

```
    '<test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
    <Value>Long</Value>
</test1>

    <test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
<Value>Long</Value>
    </test1>'
```

Can anyone give some advice on how i would delete one of these duplicate rows from the XML. I want to keep just 1 of the duplicate XML. So the output i am looking for is:

```
<test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
<Value>Long</Value>
    </test1>'
```

I know i could just use DISTINCT to select this out but how do i actually delete this duplication from the XML? Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To be honest: It might be easier to read this out in a tabular set and re-create the XML from scratch.

But XQuery can help you too:

```
create table test12
(
  id int,
  data xml
  );
```

--I added some nodes and changed the `<Value>` in order to reflect a given node

```
  insert into test12 (id,data)
  values (1,
    '<test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
    <Value>blah 1</Value>
</test1>

    <test1>
<Attribute>OneMore</Attribute>
<Value>blah 1</Value>
    </test1>

    <test1>
<Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
<Value>blah 2</Value>
    </test1>

    <test1>
<Attribute>SomeOther</Attribute>
<Value>blah 1</Value>
    </test1>'

  );
GO
```

--This is the query

```
SELECT t.id
      ,t.data.query('for $attrValue in distinct-values(/test1/Attribute/text())
                     return /test1[Attribute = $attrValue][1]')
FROM test12 t;
```

The idea in short:

The `XQuery`-function `distinct-values()` will return a distinct list of all values at the given path. In this case we get a list of `text()`-nodes back.
Now we can iterate through this list and return the first occurance of each `<test1>` element, where the `<Attribute>` equals the list variable. As result we get the first of each kind back:

```
<test1>
  <Attribute>FGHH</Attribute>
  <Value>blah 1</Value>
</test1>
<test1>
  <Attribute>OneMore</Attribute>
  <Value>blah 1</Value>
</test1>
<test1>
  <Attribute>SomeOther</Attribute>
  <Value>blah 1</Value>
</test1>
```